# Comparar arrays

Tags: php, array

Boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber como posso estar comparando dois arrays e guardando cada par de valor encontrado e imprimir os numeros que ficaram sem par.

Ex: a) 1,2,3,4,5
    b) 1,3,5,6,7,5,3

Guardaria os pares (1,1) (3,3) (5,5) e imprimia os valores 2,4,6,7,5,3
Notem que 5 e 3 também tem que ser impresso pois nao outro que guarde o par do mesmo.

Preciso saber exatamente esses valores que não tem par, mesmo sendo repetidos.
Se alguem puder dar uma luz, agradecido.

Abraços

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que esse código resulta o problema, primeiro é feito uma pesquisa no array `$b` passando o valor atual de `$a`, caso encontrado é criado uma novo elemente em `$iguais` que basicamente faz a mesma coisa que `array_diff()` e é removido esse item de `$b` para não entrar novamente na contagem. Do contrario um item é adicionado a `$diferentes`. Ao final é feita a soma dos itens que existem em `$a` que não existem em `$b` com essa linha: (`$diferentes += $b;`)

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/y567w3)

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
$b = [1,3,5,6,7,5,3];

$iguais = [];
$diferentes = [];
foreach($a as $item){
    $i = array_search($item, $b);
    if($i !== false){
        $iguais[] = '('. $item .', '. $b[$i] .')';
        unset($b[$i]);
    }else{
        $diferentes[] = $item;
    }
}

$diferentes += $b;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($iguais);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($diferentes);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (1, 1)
    [1] => (3, 3)
    [2] => (5, 5)
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 3
)
```

Comment: Obrigado rray, exatamente o que eu queria.

Comment: @GustavoFreire se resolveu o seu problema pode marcar a resposta como aceita, pode ver em => [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, ele imprimi os valores não encontrados , mas imprimi junto, teria como imprimir os valores de $a que não estão em $b e o de $b que não estão em $a, isso separadamente? Obrigado

Comment: @GustavoFreire chamar duas vezes `array_diff()` resolve o problema? `$diffab = array_diff($a, $b);
$diffba = array_diff($b, $a);` veja se é isso

Comment: Imprimiu apenas os numeros diferentes de $a, no caso faltou 8 em $b
$a = [1,2,3,4,5,7,7,9]; 
$b = [2,4,7,8,9];

IGUAIS - Array
(
    [0] => (2, 2)
    [1] => (4, 4)
    [2] => (7, 7)
    [3] => (9, 9)
)
DIFERENTES - Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 7
)

Comment: @GustavoFreire a diferença do b para o a ficou em `$diffba`

Comment: Sim, mas eu consigo imprimir em dois arrays a diferença de cada um? Por exemplo Array 1 = $diffab Array 2 = $diffba ? Pois preciso pegar os numeros de cada 1 somar e depois subtrair Array 1 de Array 2.

Answer (score 2):

O PHP possui uma função chamada [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php).

Basicamente o que ela faz é o que você quer, a diferença é que você vai precisar dar algumas iterações a mais, porque ela mostra apenas as diferenças entre dois arrays, então no próprio exemplo dado pelo site do php:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "verde", "vermelho", "azul", "vermelho");
$array2 = array("b" => "verde", "amarelo", "vermelho");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

O resultado seria

```
Array
(
  [1] => azul
)
```

O oposto dessa função seria o que você poderia procurar para fazer o primeiro passo, o [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-intersect.php) une dois arrays como um `inner join` e retorna os valores que existem em ambos:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "verde", "vermelho", "azul");
$array2 = array("b" => "verde", "amarelo", "vermelho");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Retornaria:

```
Array
(
    [a] => verde
    [0] => vermelho
)
```